# Unable to call a method in another dart file

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a dart file with IndexedStack and the following function in the same file to change the stacks.

The file with method as follows-

```
  class RootApp extends StatefulWidget  with selectedTab {
  @override
  _RootAppState createState() => _RootAppState();
}


class _RootAppState extends State<RootApp> {
  int pageIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> pages = [
    ......
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ....

    return AnimatedBottomNavigationBar(
      .......
      onTap: (index) {
        selectedTab(index);
      },
    );
  }

  selectedTab(index) {
    setState(() {
      pageIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

There is this other dart file from which i would like to call selectedTab method with value of 0. The other file is as follows---

```
class CreatBudgetPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CreatBudgetPageState createState() => _CreatBudgetPageState();
}

class _CreatBudgetPageState extends State<CreatBudgetPage> {
  .......
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('expenses/' + userId + '/' + todayDate)
        .add({
   ....
    }).then((_) {
      print("collection created");
      void rootApp() => selectedTab(0);
    }).catchError((error) {
      print(error);
    });
  }
```

How can i call this method from the other dart file?

P.S: I am a Newbie

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the function callback as parameters from the source class to the intended class and invoke the function as you want.

here is a simple example.

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  int pageIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: pageIndex,
        children: [
          Tab1Page(),
          Tab2Page(
            /// solution 1
            onPressed1: () {
              selectedTab(0);
            },

            /// solution 2
            // onPressed2: selectedTab,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'TAB 1',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'TAB 2',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: pageIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: selectedTab,
      ),
    );
  }

  selectedTab(index) {
    setState(() {
      pageIndex = index;
    });
  }
}

class Tab1Page extends StatelessWidget {
  const Tab1Page({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          "Tab1",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Tab2Page extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback? onPressed1;

  // final Function(int)? onPressed2;
  const Tab2Page({
    Key? key

    /// solution 1
    ,
    this.onPressed1,

    /// solution 2
    // this.onPressed2
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              "Tab2",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                /// solution 1
                if (onPressed1 != null) {
                  onPressed1!();
                }

                /// solution 2
                // if(onPressed2!=null){
                //   onPressed2!(0);
                //
                // }
              },
              child: Text("click to navigate to another tab",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```